# Дата сорц не подключается к бд: Connection refused: connect mysql

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

Не могу подключиться к продакшен базе данных, используя javax.sql.DataSource, ошибка:

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect mysql`

При использовании mysql workbench соединение происходит. Там я использую ssh connection. Как сделать тоже в датасорце?

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://255.255.255.255:3306/some_db");
    dataSource.setUsername("xxx");
    dataSource.setPassword("yyy");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Эта же конфигурация работает для локальной бд H2

Comment: Может база на продакшене не доступна извне и надо прокидывать ssh тунель?

Comment: Может быть, а как прокинуть ssh тоннель?

Comment: Если IP сервера `255.255.255.255`, и mysql работает на `3306` порту, то `ssh -L 33066:127.0.0.1:3306 user@255.255.255.255`. И подключаться из java к `127.0.0.1:33066`.

Comment: Но нужно ssh тоннель прокидывать тоже в java приложении

Comment: что именно ты имеешь в виду?

Comment: Ну в смысле куда мне эту строчку вставлять? `dataSource.setUrl("ssh -L 33066:127.0.0.1:3306 user@255.255.255.255);` вот так?

Comment: наверное, mysql-connector не умеет сам себе устанавливать ssh-туннель. Гугль предлагает [поднимать ssh-туннель через JSch и потом подключаться на локальный адрес](http://cryptofreek.org/2012/06/06/howto-jdbc-over-an-ssh-tunnel/)

Comment: друзья, все гораздо проще. в терминале делаем тунель, таким образом все запросы на локальный порт 33066 будут прокидываться на серверный порт 3306. и дальше `dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33066/some_db");`

Comment: если запускаешь на винде, то тунель можно строить через программу putty.

Comment: @MichaelPak Спасибо большое. Вот эта статья очень  помогла http://cryptofreek.org/2012/06/06/howto-jdbc-over-an-ssh-tunnel/

Comment: Можешь в ответ переделать какой-нибудь комментарий, если хочешь

Comment: Я пробовал еще библиотеку jsch-extension (https://github.com/lucastheisen/jsch-extension/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pastdev/jsch/tunnel/TunneledDataSourceWrapper.java), но там как-то трудоемко имплементить

Comment: @zRrr А это ты добавил статью. Тебе тогда спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, доступ к базе данных доступ только локально. Для того, чтобы удаленно подключиться к базе, надо прокинуть SSL туннель до сервера. Можно сделать двумя способами:

1. Прокинуть туннель из терминала:

   ```
   ssh -L 33066:127.0.0.1:3306 user@255.255.255.255
   ```

   А в Java подключаться следующим образом:

   ```
   dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33066/some_db");
   ```
2. Прокинуть туннель из Java. Более подробно описано [здесь](http://cryptofreek.org/2012/06/06/howto-jdbc-over-an-ssh-tunnel/).